# Error: etherbase address must be explicitly specified

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, accounts

When I make a RPC to geth running remotely, I cannot get the account list / balance of the account. It also says that the coinbase is not set. But as far as I know, isnt the coinbase supposed to be the first account created if coinbase is explicitly not defined ? If I use geth command line in the remote machine, the two accounts that I have created show up, while the RPC returns 0 accounts. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Try starting `geth` with explicit `http` flags. Note that exposing `personal` api to internet is not safe, and `personal` api is deprecated.

`geth --http --http.api="eth,personal"`

To start with all available apis (important: if you do this make sure your api is not accessible from internet)

`geth --http --http.api="admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,ethash,miner,net"`

Answer (score 5):

Create an account.

```
$ geth account new
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase:
Repeat Passphrase:
Address: {168bc315a2ee09042d83d7c5811b533620531f67}
```

Or

Creates a new account and prints the address.

On the console, use:

> personal.NewAccount()
>   ... you will be prompted for a password ...

or

> personal.newAccount("passphrase")

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

Answer (score 2):

May be it is a bit late to answer but for others if they need in future. I had a typo in `--datadir` and `--networkid`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set etherbase first:

```
~ geth console --ropsten
> miner.setEtherbase('0x..........')
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I was defining the wrong data directory. So if you are creating your own blockchain and facing this error, make sure you have specified the correct data directory.

```
sudo geth --snapshot=false  --mine --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain "*" --networkid 1999 --datadir /.ethereum/ console
```

This worked for me.
Also, *rpc* is replaced with *http*.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because coinbase wallet is not made.

In console

> personal.newAccount('anypassword')

> miner.setEtherbase(personal.listAccounts[1]);